# Lipstick in USB; Ideas about how to remove it?

Tags: usb

Ok, so I have a stupid question...  The cap came off lipstick in purse,  the thumb drive, also in the purse,  now has lipstick inside it about 1/16 of an inch. Ideas about what to do? I really need the content and am afraid to do anything that will destroy the content if any is still intact. Was getting ready to back it up as my back up thumb drive died.... (age - no abuse)

Comment: use a pin / needle and scrape it out carefully. as long as you get electrical contact on the pins once inserted you should be fine.

Comment: And then replace the thumb drive once you have copied the contents ...

Comment: Not sure this will help, but freezing the thumb drive might harden the lipstick so it breaks off rather than smearing when you try to remove it.  Afterwards, let the thumb drive come to room temperature before using it.  If there are any signs of condensation, let it dry completely before using it.

Comment: And use a USB externion cable so you don't accidentaly damage the USB port on your computer ...

Comment: … and don't use any kind of portable USB key as the sole repository for **any** data you rely on. 2 keys, an HD & a cloud would be minimum these days.

Answer (score 3):

Buy some rubbing alcohol from the supermarket.  Get the lowest percentage alcohol you can find - usually 70%.  The other 30% is benzene, which lipstick will dissolve in.  Neither are harmful to electronics and evaporate quickly.  Dip a Q-tip or similar object in the alcohol and rub away the lipstick.

Comment: 70% alcohol is 30% water.  How does 30% benzene get in there (it's carcinogenic)?

Comment: @fixer1234 We used benzene as a solvent in school chemistry 40 years ago. Had it on my hands many times. Wasn't classed as a carcinogen then :(

Comment: Many modern carcinogens are declared as such after exposing animals to ridiculous amounts of the substance. In this case, it was statistically insignificant at 300X the safe limit  [National Library of Medicine](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6959383/).

Answer (score 1):

Mineral oil and a paint brush? Non-corosive, non-conductive, probably compatible with the ingredients (may actually be an ingredient). Won't rust anything.

> Mineral oil is used in a variety of industrial/mechanical capacities
>   as a non-conductive coolant or thermal fluid in electric components as
>   it does not conduct electricity

(Wikipedia)

Note that mica or other reflective ingredients that may be in the lip stick *may* be conductive, so you want flush it really well, then "dry brush" it to remove as much excess oil as you can before attempting to plug it in.

Comment: Will try after I try the alchohol, since I have it . thank you